# how to pick only last string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this I have seen functions and Substring and LEFT ,RIGHT also
but it is not serving my purpose

```
declare @t table (val varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t(val)values ('E-001GHDEM120ENDORSEMENT'),
 ('E-001GHDEM120Renewal'),
  ('E-001GHDEM120Adjustment'),
   ('E-001GHDEM120ENDORSEMENT')
select * from @t
```

**output**

```
ENDORSEMENT
Renewal
Adjustment
ENDORSEMENT
```

I need to use that statement in where condition to filter records

Comment: Is the string "E-001GHDEM120" a constant one that occurs before the output...?  If yes, I would suggest substitute() function

Comment: Is changing the data model not an option? Each normal column should contain *one* scalar value - not lots of data slammed together into a string (which then introduces problems, such as you see here, when you now want to extract *one* of the values back out)

Comment: `substring(val, 14, 36)` didn't work?

Comment: I have tried using RIGHT function and Stuff function but not able to reach it

Comment: guys why you people are down voting not even suggesting answer

Comment: @TheKing it will keep on changing the it is not a constant

Comment: Mohan, please edit your question with the (failed) attempt(s) you made using `RIGHT` and `STUFF`. Also, if "E-001GHDEM120" is not constant please describe what possible strings your string can start with.

Comment: You mention that the prefix keeps changing but is the length of the prefix constant?  What we are looking for is some rule that will help identify the start of the required string.  Examples include: it always occurs in the same place, there is always a number before the first letter, etc.  Once we have this the SQL is relatively simple.  A good way to write this rule is to pretend you were going to process a number of rows manually.  Describe how you  would achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this select

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
                (
                 val VARCHAR(50)
                );
INSERT INTO @t
              (val
              )
VALUES
       ('E-001GHDEM120ENDORSEMENT'
       ),
       ('E-001GHDEM120Renewal'
       ),
       ('E-001GHDEM120Adjustment'
       ),
       ('E-001GHDEM120ENDORSEMENT'
       );
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(val), 0, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]%', REVERSE(val)))) AS val
FROM @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. From your example here is what i understood.

```
select right(val,patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse(val))-1) 
 from @t
```